# DWB_local_planner - Distance between the robot and the obstacle

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, move-base, avoid-obstacle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I use the [DWB_local_planner](https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation/tree/master/dwb_local_planner) and the robot gets very close to the obstacle while avoiding it.

I'm interested to configure the *DWB_local_planner* in order that the robot ALWAYS keep a certain distance (for instance 50 cm) to any obstacles.

In the [TEB_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner) there is a parameter called *min_obstacle_dist* for this issue. This distance is independent from the *local_costmap inflation_radius*.

I was wondering if you know how to configure the *DWB_local_planner* that the robot keeps a specific distance from the obstacle. In the *DWB_local_planner* parameter, as far as I understood, a specific parameter has not been dedicated for this issue.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313626/dwb_local_planner---distance-between-the-robot-and-the-obstacle/) by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2019-01-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2019-01-24**:
What do you mean an override? A change via DWB that doesn't affect the costmap?

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2019-01-24**:
I meant that I prefer to have access to the distance between the robot and the obstacle independently from the costmap. For example if the inflation radius is equal to 0.1m I can configure it to have a distance equal to 0.3m. Do you think it is possible?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2019-01-24**:
I'm still not certain what you mean. Are you asking if you can just increase the inflation_radius parameter?

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2019-01-25**:
Thanks for your reply David. I updated my question and I hope now it is clear for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So if you want the robot to NEVER go within X meters of an obstacle, I would change the robot's footprint to have an inscribed radius equal to X. This will make some feasible plans not feasible anymore.

If you want the robot to strongly prefer not going within X meters, you can increase the scale parameter on the obstacle critic in DWB.

If you want to control the logic even further, I would create a custom DWB critic that extends the MapGridCritic and use it to calculate the distance to the obstacles, and evaluate trajectories based on their distance to the obstacle.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2019-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2019-01-25**:
Thank you David!